# fit and predict model at factor level in r

Tags: r, glm, predict

I would like to fit model at factor level and use those fitted model name on fly for predicting new data at such matching factor level. I am failing in prediction in this logic, can someone guide on this considering below case?

```
Aa <- data.frame(amount=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1), cat1=sample(letters[21:24], 15,rep=TRUE),cat2=sample(letters[11:18], 5,rep=TRUE),
                   card=c("a","b","c","a","c","b","a","c","b","a","b","c","a","c","a"), delay=sample(c(1,1,0,0,0),5,rep=TRUE))

ModelFit<-sapply(as.character(unique(Aa[["card"]])), function(x)glm(delay~amount+cat1+cat2, family = "binomial", data = subset(Aa, card==x)), simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

Bb<-Aa[-(which(names(Aa) %in% "delay"))]

sapply(unique(Aa[["card"]]), function(x,y) predict(seq_along(x=ModelFit), newdata=DataOPEN[DataOPEN$SubsidiaryName],type="response"))
```

Comment: Why don't you fit `delay~(amount+cat1+cat2) * card` instead of looping?

Answer (score 0):

I have made this into a loop for simplicity. The prediction throws a warning, but seems to work. Your `DataOPEN` dataset was not provided, so I just calculated the prediction using the original Aa (new column `pred`). A final rounded version of the prediction is shown in column `pred.round`.

```
Aa <- data.frame(amount=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1), cat1=sample(letters[21:24], 15,rep=TRUE),cat2=sample(letters[11:18], 5,rep=TRUE),
                   card=c("a","b","c","a","c","b","a","c","b","a","b","c","a","c","a"), delay=sample(c(1,1,0,0,0),5,rep=TRUE))

ModelFit <- sapply(as.character(unique(Aa[["card"]])), function(x)glm(delay~amount+cat1+cat2, family = "binomial", data = subset(Aa, card==x)), simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

Aa$pred <- NaN # create a new variable for prediction

for(i in levels(Aa$card)){
  newdat <- subset(Aa, subset=card==i)
  newdat$pred <- predict(ModelFit[[i]], newdata=newdat,type="response")
  Aa$pred[match(rownames(newdat), rownames(Aa))] <- newdat$pred
}

Aa$pred.round <- round(Aa$pred) # a rounded prediction
Aa
```

The output:

```
> Aa
   amount cat1 cat2 card delay         pred pred.round
1       1    u    p    a     0 1.170226e-09          0
2       2    x    o    b     1 1.000000e+00          1
3       1    x    o    c     0 2.143345e-11          0
4       2    w    m    a     0 1.170226e-09          0
5       1    v    n    c     0 2.143345e-11          0
6       1    x    p    b     0 5.826215e-11          0
7       2    u    o    a     1 5.000000e-01          0
8       2    x    o    c     0 2.143345e-11          0
9       1    w    m    b     0 5.826215e-11          0
10      1    w    n    a     0 1.170226e-09          0
11      1    w    p    b     0 5.826215e-11          0
12      2    w    o    c     1 1.000000e+00          1
13      2    u    o    a     0 5.000000e-01          0
14      2    u    m    c     0 2.143345e-11          0
15      1    w    n    a     0 1.170226e-09          0
```

Comment: Thanks Marc! i took some time to check with my concept as i introduced "NA" for any new levels of "cat2" variables of newdataset(for predict), it is working fine for small. Let me check for my large dataset too! cheers!